# Handling assembly files in Makefile - include statement problem?

Tags: c, assembly, makefile, gnu-make

Here are parts of a `Makefile`:

```
MY_SRC += \
    scr1.c \
    src2.c \
    src3.c

BUILD_PATH=outdir
MY_OBJ := $(addprefix $(BUILD_PATH)/,$(addsuffix .o, $(MY_SRC)))
MY_DEP := $(MY_OBJ:.c.o=.c.d)

.
.
.
$(BUILD_PATH)/%.c.o: %.c
    @echo "  CC      $<"
    $(CC) $< -c $(CFLAGS) $(call MDOPT,$(@:.c.o=.c.d)) -o $@
.
.
.

-include $(MY_DEP)
```

The `MDOPT` is defined as `MDOPT = -MMD -MF $(1)`.

I needed to add assembly `.asm.s`source files, so I added:

```
MY_SRC += myfile.asm.s
.
.
.
$(BUILD_PATH)/%.s.o: %.s
    @echo "  ASM     $<"
    $(Q)$(CC) $< -c $(CFLAGS) -o $@
```

However, when trying to compile the sources, it gave me error:

```
ASM myfile.asm.s out/myfile.asm.s.o:1: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

I have found the following fix - remove the last line in the Makefile:
`-include $(MY_DEP)`.

What caused the error?
Why did removal of the `-include` line fix the problem? What is the purpose of this line at all?

Comment: You probably did not have an empty line before the `include`. It's hard to troubleshoot whitespace problems via stackoverflow especially if you do not provide full exact file.

Comment: @Jester I did have empty line. In fact, I did not even touch the last lines of the Makefile. I only added `.s` support, as above.

Comment: `out/myfile.asm.s.o` gets included because `MY_DEP := $(MY_OBJ:.c.o=.c.d)` 
doesn't convert `.s.o` to `.d`?

Comment: Yeah, good catch! Even if it did, I wonder if `.d` files are properly generated for assembly.

Comment: Indeed, that seems to be the question, how to generate `.d` files for assembly?

Comment: @Danijel Use the same mechanism as for C source files if compiling through the C compiler.

Comment: @fuz Tried it, but the file isn't generated.

Comment: While gnu assembler does support dependency generation via `-MD`, gcc doesn't seem to invoke it. You will just need to write a separate rule to generate the dependencies directly via the assembler.

Comment: @Jester Sounds like a bug report.

Comment: Figured it out: I was invoking gcc with `-MMD -MF file` options, and this didn't work for assembly. I have now done a separate `as` rule with `-MD file` option, and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was resolved in two steps:

- `MY_DEP := $(MY_OBJ:.c.o=.c.d)` did not take in the `.s` assembly files. This was fixed with:

```
MY_DEP_TEMP := $(MY_OBJ:.c.o=.c.d)
MY_DEP += $(MY_DEP_TEMP:.s.o=.s.d)
```

- Additional target for compiling `.s` files needed to be changed in order to generate `.d` files:

```
$(BUILD_PATH)/%.s.o: %.s
    @echo "  AS     $<"
    $(AS) $< -c $(ASFLAGS) $(call MDOPT_ASM,$(@:.s.o=.s.d)) -o $@
```

Special care needed to be taken with respect to `MDOPT_ASM` which needed to be defined as `MDOPT_AS = -MD $(1)`, which is different then the one for `.c` targets (`MDOPT_C = -MMD -MF $(1)`).

Answer (score 3):

> What caused the error?

The error message suggests a syntax error in the binary file
`out/myfile.asm.s.o`. The error isn't detected at include time because
the `-include` directive was used (try `info make include`, near the
end). `myfile.asm.s` is appended to `MY_SRC`, and `out/myfile.asm.s.o`
therefore to `MY_OBJ` and `MY_DEP`. The binary file gets included
because `MY_DEP := $(MY_OBJ:.c.o=.c.d)` leaves `.s.o` intact.

**UPDATE**: To be more precise about the timeline,

1. `make`, on seeing `-include $(MY_DEP)`, decides it can remake the
   requested `.s.so` file from an implicit rule; no errors at this
   point, even if it could not be remade
2. builds the `.s.so` displaying the output from `@echo` but not the
   `$(CC)` command line (since `$(Q)` expands to `@`, it seems); no errors yet
3. reads and parses the `.s.so` as a makefile, fails on line 1, and
   terminates with an error message (end **UPDATE**)

> Why did removal of the `-include` line fix the problem?

It skips reading `out/myfile.asm.s.o` which isn't a makefile.

> What is the purpose of this line at all?

See `info make 'Automatic Prerequisites'`.